# Karate contains only shortcut fails in v1.2.0

Tags: karate

According to Karate documentation for [contains short-cuts](https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/#contains-short-cuts) The following match arguments should work and do the same:

```
@test_contains_only
Scenario: Test contains only shortcut
  * def expected = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
  * def to_match = { "properties": { "additional_information": "Some put-updated info", "types": [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ] } }
  * print to_match.properties.relation_types
    
  # This will pass
  * match to_match.properties contains deep 
    """
    {
    "additional_information": "Some put-updated info", 
    "types": [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
    }
    """

  # This will pass
  * match to_match.properties.types == '#(^^expected)'
    
  # This will fail
  * match to_match.properties contains deep 
    """
    {
    "additional_information": "Some put-updated info", 
    "types": '#(^^expected)'
    }
    """
```

When executing the above, I get this error:

```
* match to_match.properties contains deep
"""
{
"additional_information": "Some put-updated info", 
"types": '#(^^expected)'
}
"""
match failed: CONTAINS_DEEP
  $ | actual does not contain expected | all key-values did not match, expected has un-matched keys - [types] (MAP:MAP)
  {"additional_information":"Some put-updated info","types":["a","b","c","d"]}
  {"additional_information":"Some put-updated info","types":"#(^^expected)"}

    $.types | actual does not contain expected | actual array does not contain expected item - #(^^expected) (LIST:STRING)
    ["a","b","c","d"]
    '#(^^expected)'

      $.types[3] | data types don't match (STRING:LIST)
      'd'
      ["a","b","c","d"]

      $.types[2] | data types don't match (STRING:LIST)
      'c'
      ["a","b","c","d"]

      $.types[1] | data types don't match (STRING:LIST)
      'b'
      ["a","b","c","d"]

      $.types[0] | data types don't match (STRING:LIST)
      'a'
      ["a","b","c","d"]
```

In my opinion, using `'#(^^expected)'` doesn't work as expected. Or is it happening because I'm using `match to_match.properties contains deep` together with the `^^` (contains only shortcut)?

I'm using *Karate* **v1.2.0**. The same scenario doesn't fail in **v1.0.1**.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is fixed in 1.2.1.RC2: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2007

Else please file an issue. Ideally a PR ;)

Comment: 1.2.1.RC2 didn't solve the issue. I've moved contains shortcuts from `deep contains` steps into a separate step to make it pass. I'll link this question in the bug you've mentioned above. Anyhow, this issue might involve other contains shortcuts as well, for me it was failing on `^^` and `^+`.